# Characterization of splitting of irreducible polynomial with prime degree field generated by two roots

Tags: galois-theory

Let K be a finite dimension extension of the rationals.
Let f ∈ K[x] be irreducible of prime degree, and L be the splitting field of f over K.
Prove that L is generated by two of the roots of f if and only if each non identity automorphism in Gal(L/K) has at most one fixed point.
I think it is linked to this theorem: An irreducible polynomial of prime degree in Q  is solvable by radicals if and only if its splitting field is generated by any two roots of the polynomials.
PS: any reference for the proof is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like we are to think of $Gal(L/K)$ as acting on the set of roots of $f$. When discussing fixed points, that is :-)

Comment: What is the significance of the fact that the field is generated by two roots? On the basis of: always think about the given conditions.